# Using string_agg() over n rows of data grouped by a Common Key

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression, recursive-cte

I would like to use `string_agg(column_name,',')` on some IDs in a column from a SQL result set. I would be grouping by a single key, but also want to make sure each grouped set results in n rows being fed into the `string_agg(column_name,',')` function

Example:

```
create table #temp (first_name varchar(20), data_id char(3))
insert into #temp (first_name, data_id) values('jeff', 'XX1')
insert into #temp (first_name, data_id) values('jeff', 'X23')
insert into #temp (first_name, data_id) values('jeff', 'X87')
insert into #temp (first_name, data_id) values('jeff', 'X09')
insert into #temp (first_name, data_id) values('jeff', 'X15')

insert into #temp (first_name, data_id) values('bob', 'X76')
insert into #temp (first_name, data_id) values('bob', 'X17')
insert into #temp (first_name, data_id) values('bob', 'X98')
insert into #temp (first_name, data_id) values('bob', 'X99')

select * from #temp

first_name  data_id
      jeff      XX1
      jeff      X23
      jeff      X87
      jeff      X09
      jeff      X15
       bob      X76
       bob      X17
       bob      X98
       bob      X99
```

Ideal result I am trying to create for lets say, n = 3 rows string aggregated per group is below. in the event that there are <3 rows left for that particular `first_name` key, throw the remaining into the column.

I am trying to use a recursive CTE but can't quite wrap my head around it

```
first_name        data_id
      jeff    XX1,X23,X87
      jeff        X09,X15
       bob    X76,X17,X98
       bob            X99
```

Comment: which version of sql server?

Comment: @nbk Version is 2019

Comment: is data_id always consecutive?

Comment: @DannySlor nope, the actual numbers have no meaning here. I'll edit the question to clear up the confusion. My early thought was to try a ```row_number() over (partition by first_name order by first_name)``` but couldn't quite fill in the blanks to get the solution

Comment: I got you. that's part of it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select  first_name
       ,string_agg(data_id, ',') as data_id
from    (
        select  *
                ,(row_number() over(partition by first_name order by data_id)-1)/3 as grp
        from     #temp
        ) t
group by first_name, grp
order by first_name
```

| first_name | data_id |
| --- | --- |
| bob | X17,X76,X98 |
| bob | X99 |
| jeff | X09,X15,X23 |
| jeff | X87,XX1 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/q7g4_F--)

Comment: Masterful work. Thank you!